# Setting up private ethereum testnet

Tags: ethereum, geth

I am setting up a private ethereum testnet using geth. 
this is the genesis file.my question is when i create new accounts using personal.newAccount() command do i have to replace these addresses with the new ones ? and initialize the json file again?

i have already tried running this file and the mining starts but the account balance does not go up.

```
{
   "config": {
      "chainId": 1994,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0
   },
   "difficulty": "400",
   "gasLimit": "2000000",
   "alloc": {
      "7b684d27167d208c66584ece7f09d8bc8f86ffff": { 
          "balance": "100000000000000000000000" 
      },
      "ae13d41d66af28380c7af6d825ab557eb271ffff": { 
          "balance": "120000000000000000000000" 
      }
   }
}
```

The mining thread gets killed and connection from geth java console times out.

Answer (score 0):

By defining these addresses in the genesis file, the addresses are not generated as accounts, only pre-funded. I would recommend you to generate 1-2 accounts and use these account addresses as the pre-funded addresses.

Regarding this: **"i have already tried running this file and the mining starts but the account balance does not go up."**

It doesn't increase because no mining address/account is specified.
In your case, after starting `miner.start()`, the mining process is killed, because no etherbase/coinbase account is specified. Normally the etherbase/coinbase will be assigned to the first account. If you don't want to create an account, an assignment of the etherbase is necessary.
I assume that something like this is thrown:

> Error: etherbase missing: etherbase address must be explicitly specified

You can set the address via this command:
`miner.setEtherbase("7b684d27167d208c66584ece7f09d8bc8f86ffff")`

All in all you have two options:

- Create an account and use this as your etherbase
- Assign the etherbase to your prefunded address

By creating an account, the etherbase will be automatically assigned to this account.
I hope, I could help you.